# Requests via Sense chrome extension to elasticsearch breaks when ID contains @

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, sense

Trying to add documents to an elasticsearch index using Sense. eg:

```
POST productmarket/ppt/joe@broker.com_Index_withNewGuid_233df4
{
 "hash" : "cake"   
}
```

and I get back"

```
Request failed to get to the server (status code: 0):
```

Now if I change the @ to something else it works fine.

Now we already have items in the index that have @'s in the id's. If I update them in a frontend APP we have that uses the API's to post it breaks as well eg.

[image]

BUT When I use our C# app to index a json document that has @ in its id using NEST it works. And when I try and update this document again in the frontend app (where it just broke) it works as well.

Now I have tried indexing plain document and complex documents. Nothing changes. I've tried different indexes. Still the same problem.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Just check the source code for the client that I wrote there might be an issue in there?

Comment: Yes. But the client works fine if the document was indexed using NEST. But if I'm trying to update an old document with @ in its name from the client it doesn't work. Its not just the client though, in Sense as well, it doesn't want to post when there is an @ in the ID and gives back that `Request failed to get to the server (status code: 0):`

Comment: Works for me with ES 1.3.4, Marvel 1.2.1

Comment: @AndreiStefan So you can post via the Sense plugin for chrome using @ in the iD? Just to confirm.

Comment: `http://localhost:9200/_plugin/marvel/sense/index.html` haven't installed anything in Chrome (version 39.0.2171.71) and I used the exact command you posted. This is the response: `{
   "_index": "productmarket",
   "_type": "ppt",
   "_id": "joe@broker.com_Index_withNewGuid_233df4",
   "_version": 1,
   "created": true
}`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @AndreiStefan . We don't have the marvel plugin. I'm going to test this from another pc then move from there. I'm pretty sure this worked before even last night.

Comment: Thanks for your help @AndreiStefan, Sense doesn't url encode the @ hence it breaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Pretty stupid.

Nest URL encodes the request.
Sense does not. Using the URL encoded value for @ it works fine.